# Calling external PHP file with Mootools

Tags: php, joomla, mootools

I am attempting to include the output of an external PHP script into a Joomla article using Mootools but cannot get it to work  This is what I have in the source of my article
Code:

```
<div id="opt-out"></div>
<script>
window.addEvent('domready',function() {
  $('opt-out').load('http://analytics.xyz.com/index.php?module=CoreAdminHome&amp;action=optOut');
});
</script>
```

Have probably got the syntax completely wrong so any help gratefully appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Check it in Mozilla firebug it must be giving some javascript error.Coressponding to security of a breach of same origin policy. You cannot call an external script using javascript.

Comment: $("opt-out").load is not a function

Comment: `.load` is an element shortcut that can get the contents of an element updated through Request but it needs it to be local (same origin policy). if you don't even have the .load prototype defined (do `console.log(Element.prototype.load);` to check) then you're using an old version of mootools (1.11?). upgrading won't help though. flawed logic.